# Struggling using a second monitor with my laptop

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I am struggling using a second monitor with my laptop. I tried the different solutions I found in other topics with no clue.

The output of xrandr is:

```
    xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00* 
  1920x1200_60.00 (0x2b5) 193.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2056 end 2256 total 2592 skew    0 clock  74.56KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1245           clock  59.88Hz
```

but this seems to be related to the laptop monitor and not the external one.

In `Settings` I can only see `Screen Display` and not other displays appear or any identify button.

It's a philips monitor, if that could help.

**EDIT**

This is what I see in `Software and Updates`:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S5ZR.png)

Comment: May you specify what type of laptop this is, if it has discrete graphics or not, and what kind of cable you're using to connect to the second monitor?

Comment: Also any BIOS/UEFI firmware settings regarding use of discrete graphics, and which video driver you are using. Sometimes a second monitor is only available when discrete graphics are enabled, and the proprietary driver is used.

Comment: Sure guys, @Gordster my laptop has an nvidia graphic card, and an intel graphic card integrated in the motherboard.

Comment: @ubfan1 can you help me find these information for you?

Comment: You have an Nvidia  GTX 970M, which under Ubuntu 18.04, takes the 390 driver from the standard repositories. Your posted image indicates you probably used the graphics-drivers ppa, (unnecessary, so remove it).  purge the nvidia packages you have installed (probably the wrong ones), and then from that additional drivers page, you should see all the Nvidia drivers marked as proprietary (not open source), and the 400 ones not even shown (pick the 390 and apply). See https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers for detail instructions, but there are many other answers.

Comment: Hi @ubfan1, thanks again :) I have purged the drivers with sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia*' and then selected, as you said 390 and applied. Ubuntu is still not able to detect the monitor I am afraid.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't like the 390 drivers, as it was giving at startup the error: hdaudioCOD2 unable to bind the codec. With 440 it's happy.

Comment: Still not able to have Ubuntu detecting the monitor though. Any other possible suggestions?